# How to get smsc number android?

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am using below code to get MessageCenter number:

```
public String fetch(Context context) {
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex("service_center");
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
    return "";
}
```

but getting wrong smsc number, return number +91********04 whereas in device for Vodafone network provider is +919888009998?

Answer (score 0):

Get the raw PDU from the message with the function

```
android.telephony.SmsMessage.getPdu()
```

Comment: are you need message number centre or other mobile no? say clearly message centre number set based by your network service

Comment: Which one getPdu()? No.